# Checkboxes returning true all the times

Tags: php, checkbox

Any reason why the code returns me both `true` all the time ?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item1" id="item1" value="true">
<input type="checkbox" name="item2" id="item2" value="true">
```

My print_r($_POST) returns:

```
Array
(
    [item1] => true
    [item2] => true
)
```

whereas no checkboxes are checked...

Thanks for your help.

-

## UPDATE:

I found that in the code:

Is i possible this is the problem ?

```
$.(".checkbox input[type='checkbox'], .radio input[type='radio']").each(function() {
    if ($.(this).is(":checked")) {
        $.(this).closest(".checkbox").addClass("checked");
        $.(this).closest(".radio").addClass("checked");
    }
});
$.(".checkbox input[type='checkbox']").bind("change", function() {
    if ($.(this).is(":checked")) {
        $.(this).closest(".checkbox").addClass("checked");
    } else {
        $.(this).closest(".checkbox").removeClass("checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: Because the values on both are both set to true. Set `value=""` and then the checked one will be posted.

Comment: What value you expect instead of this?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard, if I do not put `true`, it makes just `on`.

Comment: What do you expect the value of a checkbox to be @popol? They are either 'on' or 'off' (and in this case, not sent or posted)

Comment: If the checkbox is not check, just `off` or anything but not `true`.